# Does Until <month-name> mean before the month starts or before the month ends?

Tags: meaning-in-context, time

I received an email stating,

> All applicants will be notified of a decision, via email, sometime from now until June.

Should I assume I would receive decision within May 31st or any day ***during*** the entire month of June?

Comment: As it looks, the communication may be sent from the time of issuing the communication to the end of June, which means it can happen by or before June 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ambiguous.  Safest reading is to be prepared for it to take a long time, so notification might come during June.  The phrasing of the example is a little odd.  I probably would have phrased as something like, "Notifications will be sent before the end of June."

Use of "until" is often clearer when it is used with a negative.  "I won't send out notifications until June" clearly means that the notification can be sent during June or after.  There potentially is a technical argument that your example should be using "until" in the same way as that negative, which would mean that the period of time ends as soon as June starts -- so the notifications have to be sent before June.  But if that's the intended meaning, it could be expressed a lot more clearly.